# Matplotlib dates/time dissappears with Qt4Agg Backend

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm currently working on a project to that includes plotting timeseries in a PyQt4 Application. I'm using the Qt4Agg backend from matplotlib and python3.3 on 64-bit Linux system.

Plotting works fine, but whenever I try to change something via the figureoptions button (the one with the green checkmark) the date/time format on the x-axis gets replaced by floats.

I've included some simple code, that shows the problem (Open the figureoptions dialog and press apply!)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x=[]
y=[]
for hour in range(0,13):
    x.append(datetime.datetime(2013,11,14,hour))
    y.append(20)
plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')
plt.plot_date(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour?

I've searched stackoverflow.com, the matplotlib faq, docs and mailing list, but couldn't find any answer.

I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just for the record how i solved this issue.

in my class i redefined enterEvent such that everytime the mouse enters the window it updates the xaxis. Of course this doesn't work whith the above example but in a proper class like in this one: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/qt_mpl_bars.py.txt

```
def enterEvent(self, event):
    self.axes.get_xaxis()._update_axisinfo()
    self.canvas.draw()
```

this is not perfect, but a workaround!